# Texto que se digita aos Poucos?

Tags: javascript, html

Gente, Eu vejo um efeito nos sites. O Texto vai aparecendo (Como se alguém estivesse digitando ele). Automaticamente eu relacionei á marquee, mas o efeito não é legal.
Vocês sabem como fazer?

Comment: Caso esteja usando `jQuery`, existe esse plugin que facilita o desenvolvimento da sua necessidade. http://www.mattboldt.com/demos/typed-js/

Answer (score 22):

Isso é +/- simples. Um exemplo seria assim:

```js
var div = document.getElementById('log');
var texto = 'Hoje está um lindo dia!';

function escrever(str, el) {
  var char = str.split('').reverse();
  var typer = setInterval(function() {
    if (!char.length) return clearInterval(typer);
    var next = char.pop();
    el.innerHTML += next;
  }, 100);
}

escrever(texto, div);
```

```html
<div id="log"></div>
```

De uma string de texto ele parte a string numa array, caracter por caracter e inverte a ordem (para poder usar o `.pop`).

Depois usando o `setInterval` e `.pop()` vams esvaziando essa array com texto.

#### jsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/yLy0jxeb/1/

Comment: o mais bonito deste código é o clearInterval ;D

Answer (score 6):

Alternativa:

```js
var texto = "Hello World!!!";
var result;

var count = 0;
function digitar() {
  result = document.getElementById("result");
  window.setTimeout(function() { inserir(texto[count]) }, 200);
}

function inserir(letra) {
  result.innerHTML += letra;
  count++;
  if(count < texto.length)
    window.setTimeout(function() { inserir(texto[count]) }, 200);
}

window.onload = digitar;
```

```html
<div id="result"></div>
```

Answer (score 6):

Alternativa ao código do colega [Sergio], tão somente para colocar tudo em uma função, sem ter variáveis globais (que dificilmente serão usadas por outras funções)

```
function typeWritter(texto,idElemento,tempo){
    var char = texto.split('').reverse();
    var typer = setInterval(function () {
        if (!char.length) return clearInterval(typer);
        var next = char.pop();
        document.getElementById(idElemento).innerHTML += next;
    }, tempo);
}
typeWritter('Hoje está um lindo dia!','log',100);
```

```js
function typeWritter(texto,idElemento,tempo){
    var char = texto.split('').reverse();
    var typer = setInterval(function () {
        if (!char.length) return clearInterval(typer);
        var next = char.pop();
        document.getElementById(idElemento).innerHTML += next;
    }, tempo);
}
typeWritter('Hoje está um lindo dia!','log',100);
```

```html
<div id="log"></div>
```

**JsFiddle http://jsfiddle.net/yLy0jxeb/15/**

Comment: Oi Rodrigo! Só agora vi a tua resposta :) 
Quando dizes _"colocar tudo em uma função, sem ter variáveis globais"_ isso é o que eu fiz... Não há variáveis globais no meu código e está tudo numa função... podes explicar melhor a diferênça que apontas?

Comment: As variáveis que colocou como globais foram div e texto, nas duas primeiras linhas do seu código. O que eu fiz foi colocá-las dentro da função. A intenção foi apenas mostrar o uso sem elas e passando o id do elemento ao invés do próprio elemento. É uma mera alternativa, seu código está correto. :D

Comment: Havia esquecido, coloquei um parâmetro para o tempo da digitação.

Answer (score 3):

Uma alternativa ao código do [Sergio] utilizando uma função anônima:

```js
(function() {
  var node = document.getElementById('message'),
    message = "This is my message... ! Thx =)",
    current = message.split("").reverse(),
    interval = setInterval(function() {
      if (current.length)
        node.innerHTML += current.pop();
      else
        clearInterval(interval);
    }, 300);
}());
```

```html
<div id="message"></div>
```