# Texto que se escreve aos poucos, apaga e escreve outro

Tags: javascript, html

Eu gostaria do script para um texto que se escreve aos poucos.
Achei facilmente aqui no SOpt, o link é este:
[Texto que se digita aos Poucos?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/64021/texto-que-se-digita-aos-poucos)

Porém, gostaria de um incremento que não achei.
Seguinte: após ele terminar de escrever o texto, apagar tudo e escrever um texto diferente. Também gostaria de um loop infinito disso.
Ex:

> Escreve texto 1
>
> Apaga
>
> Escreve texto 2
>
> Apaga
>
> Escreve texto 1
>
> Apaga

E por aí vai.

Comment: O que já tentou fazer?

Comment: Apenas usei o mesmo código da postagem que citei. Eu não entendo de JS, mas gostaria deste código em meu site.

Comment: Lá há duas alternativas. Se usou algum deles e tentou adaptar sem sucesso, seria interessante adicionar aqui o código que você adaptou, mesmo que não funcione, assim ele se torna uma base para uma resposta.

Comment: Ambos funcionaram. Mas o propósito dos códigos naquela postagem, é exibir apenas uma postagem. Eu não fiz alterações, não entendo de javascript, apenas PHP.

Comment: Basta colocar em um temporizador, ele vai chamar a cada 8 segundos passando um texto, esse texto pode ser um array randomico, ou uma lista dentro de um for: `function escreveInfinito(texto) {
setInterval(() => { //...poe todo esse código aqui, e pronto...  }, 8000); escreveInfinito();`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

No seguimento dessa minha outra resposta, desenvolvendo mais o código podia ser algo assim (em versão assíncrona):

```
var div = document.getElementById('log');
var textos = ['Hoje está um lindo dia!', 'Ontem também... lindo lindo!', 'Amanha ouvi dizer que vai chover... vamos ver...', 'Boa noite, até amanhã.', 'Bons sonhos...zzZZZzzzz......'];

function escrever(str, done) {
    var char = str.split('').reverse();
    var typer = setInterval(function() {
        if (!char.length) {
            clearInterval(typer);
            return setTimeout(done, 500); // só para esperar um bocadinho
        }
        var next = char.pop();
        div.innerHTML += next;
    }, 100);
}

function limpar(done) {
    var char = div.innerHTML;
    var nr = char.length;
    var typer = setInterval(function() {
        if (nr-- == 0) {
            clearInterval(typer);
            return done();
        }
        div.innerHTML = char.slice(0, nr);
    }, 100);
}

function rodape(conteudos, el) {
    var atual = -1;
    function prox(cb){
        if (atual < conteudos.length - 1) atual++;
        else atual = 0;
        var str = conteudos[atual];
        escrever(str, function(){
            limpar(prox);
        });
    }
    prox(prox);
}
rodape(textos);
```

#### exemplo: http://jsfiddle.net/mwt4bd4r/

Se não fôr preciso limpar como eu coloquei no exemplo em cima, então pode ficar mais simples... algo como:

```
function escrever(str, done) {
    var char = str.split('').reverse();
    var typer = setInterval(function() {
        if (!char.length) {
            clearInterval(typer);
            return setTimeout(done, 500); // só para esperar um bocadinho
        }
        var next = char.pop();
        div.innerHTML += next;
    }, 100);
}

function rodape(conteudos, el) {
    var atual = -1;
    function prox(){
        if (atual < conteudos.length - 1) atual++;
        else atual = 0;
        var str = conteudos[atual];
        escrever(str, function(){
            div.innerHTML = '';
            prox();
        });
    }
    prox();
}
rodape(textos);
```

#### exemplo: http://jsfiddle.net/mwt4bd4r/1/

Comment: +1, funcionou bem até no Internet Explorer do Windows 10 Mobile. O typedjs não funcionou como esperado.

Comment: @renan ótimo! Também te dei `+1` e dava outro `+1` pelo *'Eu queria o Superuser PT'* :D

Comment: Olá. Testarei aqui e logo logo informo resultados. Desde já, obrigado pela resposta.

Comment: Funcionou perfeitamente. Exatamente o que eu queria. Obrigado.

Answer (score 3):

Existe o [Typed](http://www.mattboldt.com/demos/typed-js/) que faz o que você está buscando, podendo definir intervalos no tempo de digitação, quebras de linhas, etc. No [*readme*](https://github.com/mattboldt/typed.js#readme) do projeto há maiores informações sobre como customizá-lo, caso seja preciso.

Para o efeito que está buscando, basta isto:

```js
$(function(){
  $('#text').typed({
    strings: [
      'Eu queria o Superuser PT',
      'Mas... ^1000 ... ^1000 tudo bem...',
      'Me contento somente com o StackOverflow em Português mesmo :)'
    ],
    typeSpeed: 0
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://raw.githubusercontent.com/mattboldt/typed.js/master/dist/typed.min.js"></script>

<span id='text'></span>
```

Se quiser o cursor piscando, é preciso adicionar uma regra no seu CSS, ver no trecho de código abaixo:

```js
$(function(){
  $('#text').typed({
    strings: [
      'Eu queria o Superuser PT',
      'Mas... ^1000 ... ^1000 tudo bem...',
      'Me contento somente com o StackOverflow em Português mesmo :)'
    ],
    typeSpeed: 0
  });
});
```

```css
.typed-cursor {
    opacity: 1;
    -webkit-animation: blink 0.7s infinite;
            animation: blink 0.7s infinite;
}

@keyframes blink {
    0%, 100% { opacity:1 }
    50%      { opacity:0 }
}

@-webkit-keyframes blink {
    0%, 100% { opacity:1 }
    50%      { opacity:0 }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://raw.githubusercontent.com/mattboldt/typed.js/master/dist/typed.min.js"></script>

<span id='text'></span>
```