# Auto inserir um texto da sequência

Tags: javascript

Tenho várias palavras e gostaria que fossem inseridas em sequência com um intervalo de 5 minutos em um formulário. Já pesquisei muito mas até agora nada. 
Espero que alguém me ajude a criar esse javascript automático. O código não pode ser mudado:

```
<form id="procurar-form" method="get" action="Site">
  <input type="text" class="procurar-field" placeholder="Vamos Procurar?" name="q" value="verde"> 
  <button class="procurar-btn" id="button_procurar">Procurar</button>
</form>
```

Comment: DMelo, dá uma olhada aqui: https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/64022/129 é isso que procuras mas com um intervalos de tempo maior?

Comment: Muito obrigado pela resposta, mas não é o que preciso. Como eu disse são várias palavras e o meu código não tem id para o javascript. O tempo não é problema. Se for possível coloque o código javascript completo pra eu ver se funciona.

Comment: Onde estão essas várias palavras? O que você quer dizer por "inseridas em sequência"? Cada nova palavra será adicionada ao `input` sem excluir as antigas ou cada palavra irá aparecer sozinha por 5 minutos?

Comment: São palavras aleatórias. Por exemplo: Lata, Vidro, Papel, Terra, etc. Todas as palavras eu tenho em um arquivo txt, mas se for dificil o javascript pegar o txt as palavras podem ficar no próprio javascript. Em sequência significa uma de cada vez inserida no input sozinha a cada 5 minutos.

Comment: De fato o JavaScript não possui acesso ao arquivo e terão de estar diretamente no código.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Primeiro, dos objetos que serão responsáveis por manipular o DOM e da lista de palavras:

```
const form = document.getElementById("procurar-form");
const input = form.getElementsByTagName("input")[0];
const button = document.getElementById("button_procurar");

const palavras = ["Papel", "Vidro", "Lata", "Terra", "etc"];
```

Segundo, precisamos escrever uma função que gere um valor aleatório, atualize a palavra dentro do campo e execute o clique do botão (este último foi solicitado nos comentários). Para tal, fazemos:

```
function novaPalavra() {
  // Gera um valor aleatório de 0 ao comprimento da lista de palavras:
  const index = Math.floor(Math.random() * palavras.length);

  // Atualiza o valor do campo para a palavra sorteada:
  input.value = palavras[index];

  // Executa o clique do botão:
  button.click();
}
```

Esta função faz o desejado, mas também foi solicitado que este código seja executado a cada 5 minutos. Para tal, podemos utilizar a função `setInterval`, que recebe o nome de uma função e o intervalo que a mesma será executada, em milissegundos. Para um intervalo de 5 minutos, precisamos de um intervalo de 5*60*1000 milissegundos. Assim:

```
setInterval(novaPalavra, 5*60*1000);
```

Desta forma, a cada 5 minutos a palavra no campo será alterada para uma outra de forma aleatória e um clique no botão será executado.

Veja funcionando:

```js
const form = document.getElementById("procurar-form");
const input = form.getElementsByTagName("input")[0];
const button = document.getElementById("button_procurar");

const palavras = ["Papel", "Vidro", "Lata", "Terra", "etc"];

function novaPalavra() {
  const index = Math.floor(Math.random() * palavras.length);
  input.value = palavras[index];
  button.click();
}

setInterval(novaPalavra, 1000);
```

```html
<form id="procurar-form" method="get" action="Site">
  <input type="text" class="procurar-field" placeholder="Vamos Procurar?" name="q" value="verde"> 
  <button class="procurar-btn" id="button_procurar">Procurar</button>
</form>
```

> Dado que o clique do botão irá submeter o formulário, atualizando a página - ou redirecionando o usuário - não faz sentido algum ter um código que execute a cada 5 minutos, pois sempre na sua primeira execução o mesmo irá parar devida a submissão do formulário. A resposta foi dada desta forma pela insistência do autor nos comentários.

Comment: Puxa! Muito obrigado! Depois de mais de uma semana pesquisando e testando vários códigos agora sim!!! Teria como acrescentar um click automático no button pra ficar perfeito?

Comment: O que seria esse *click* automático? Isso irá submeter o formulário e não estava descrito na pergunta. O que realmente você precisa fazer?

Comment: O primeiro funcionou mas o segundo não. Desculpe não ter colocado esse meu desejo pois pensei que seria fácil pra eu fazer, mas até agora não consegui colocar um auto click nesse formulário.

Comment: Que primeiro? Que segundo? Por quê você precisa executar um *click* automático? Se o *click* for executado, o formulário seria submetido fazendo uma requisição GET à página `Site`. É isso que precisa? Então por quê mudar a palavra no `input` se nunca passará da primeira?

Comment: Mas não faz sentido executar esse *click* sendo que o formulário será submetido e o usuário será redirecionado de página. **Por quê precisa fazer isso?**

Comment: O site de destino tem o mesmo código por isso pode ser feito várias vezes. Preciso fazer isso várias vezes mas gostaria de deixar no modo automático.

Comment: @DMelo ainda assim não faz sentido o que você está pedindo, mas atualizei a resposta.

Comment: Perfeito! Perfeito! Perfeito! Valeu! Muito obrigado!

Comment: @DMelo https://pt.stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers

Answer (score 0):

Pode tentar assim:

```js
var input = document.getElementById("procurar-field");

var palavras = ["Lata", "Vidro", "Papel", "Terra"];

function inserePalavras(index) {
   if (index < palavras.length) {
    input.value = palavras[index];
    
    var botao = document.getElementById("button_procurar");
    botao.click();
    
    setTimeout(function() { inserePalavras(index+1); }, 1000); // Para 5 minutos basta mudar o 1000 para 300000
   }
}

setTimeout(function() { inserePalavras(0); }, 1000); // Para 5 minutos basta mudar o 1000 para 300000
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form id="procurar-form"  method="get" action="javascript:void(0)">
  <input type="text" class="procurar-field" id="procurar-field" placeholder="Vamos Procurar?" name="q" value="verde"> 
  <button class="procurar-btn" id="button_procurar">Procurar</button>
</form>
```

Depois que todos as palavras são inseridas o código para a execução do `setTimeout` para não ficar um loop infinito.

**Assim que trocar a palavra na `input` e executado um `click automático` no botão Procurar**

Obs: Troquei o `action="Site"` do formulário para `action="javascript:void(0)"` para não recarregar e poder mostrar aqui no **stackoverflow** quando for usar e só voltar o action `action="Site"`